# CSS speed optimisation - Why multiple files are better then only one?

Tags: css, caching, optimization, httprequest

**Less HTTP request the better** it's, right ?

Regarding to Google best practice explanation, **less unused css rules is also better**.

- The browser's CSS engine has to evaluate every rule contained in the file to see if the rule applies to the current page.
- Even if a stylesheet is in an external file that is cached, rendering is blocked until the browser loads the stylesheet from disk.

In your opinion what's giving better performance :

- One css file per page.
- One general css that will be cached (even if there will be +70% unused css / but avoiding any other http requests).

[Google speed best-practice](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload?hl=fr#RemoveUnusedCSS)

Comment: Can you be specific with your problem?

Comment: Less unused CSS rules only matter when you've a high traffic website like Facebook where bytes matter...

Comment: Updated - High traffic website should do all possible optimizations, and i would prioritize less HTTP request and slower on client rendering. More information on why would be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the important sentence to note from the Google best practice document is "Often, many web sites reuse the same external CSS file for all of their pages, even if many of the rules defined in it don't apply to the current page".

This needs to be taken into account as if the css file has additional code that is never going to be used if user does not visit the page for which this redundant code applies then we are certainly wasting the bandwidth which may not be a proper trade off for an additional HTTP request.

This leads to additional time to load the file plus the time wasted in evaluation of that redundant code.

Certainly using multiple files for just a single page (like different header/footer css files) would be a bad practice.

And as you know that there is not a perfect solution for any problem. You have to choose the best thing that suits your need.

So, I would say the decision to use multiple files or a single file is solely based on the overall structure of website and other trade offs.

Comment: Additional time to load the file, but then it's in cache & re-usable. But i guess that in final, one css file per page is globally more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Loading CSS is usually extremely quick. CSS blocking is something you will probably never catch. Whereas JavaScript could do so that you are visually aware that it's being downloaded. (white spaces while rendering the page).
In reality one CSS is good enough, because of a single HTTP request.
Optimization should go towards JavaScript, because this is where you can see the page slowing down. We are talking about a second-two of a difference or less here.

[Here is a site](http://tools.pingdom.com/) where you can enter URL and it will check load times. In the graph below you can compare CSS load times.